# Proper function integration

Tags: integration

How can I solve this:

$$\int \frac{x}{x^{2}-5x+4}dx$$

I have tried to write with this method  $$\int \frac{x}{(x-4)(x-1)}dx = \int \frac{A}{x-1}dx+\int \frac{B}{x-4}dx$$ 
so I get $A=-\frac{1}{3}$ and $B=\frac{4}{3}$ and when write them in their place I get: $\frac{4}{3}\ln (x-4) - \frac{1}{3}\ln (x-1) + C$

But the answer is $\frac{1}{2}\ln(x^{2}-5x+4)+\frac{5}{6}\ln \frac{x-4}{x-1}+c$

Comment: What answer did you get?  Show us some working - what did you get for A and B?  did you check that by multiplying back?

Comment: Where did this approach go wrong?

Comment: Your answer seems correct. What are you asking?

Comment: @YuriyS no, it isn't  I have the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both answer are identical.

$$\log(x^2-5x+4)=\log(x-4)+\log(x-1)$$
and
$$\log\frac{x-4}{x-1}=\log(x-4)-\log(x-1).$$

A common trap.

---

The answer in the book was probably obtained via

$$\int\frac x{x^2-4x+5}dx=\frac12\int\frac{2x-4}{x^2-4x+5}dx+2\int\frac 1{x^2-4x+5}dx.$$

Comment: What about the case where $1<x<4$. You need absolute value.

Comment: @hamam_Abdallah: right, but I am not discussing the domain of the solution, I am commenting about the answers by the OP and by the book, as are.

Comment: @YvesDaoust but the answers are not identical

Comment: @GamarMustafa: ah, you missed my answer.

Comment: @YvesDaoust what? I didn't understand, I mean $\frac{1}{2}\ln(x^{2}-5x+4)+\frac{5}{6}\ln \frac{x-4}{x-1}+c$ and $\frac{4}{3}\ln (x-4) - \frac{1}{3}\ln (x-1) + C$ are not same

Comment: @GamarMustafa: they are.

Comment: @YvesDaoust well, can you explain to me that how they are the same, please?

Comment: @GamarMustafa: this is explained by the four first lines of my answer. Care to compute.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Oh, yes I understood. Thanks a lot)

Answer (score 0):

Your integrand is continuous at $(-\infty,1), (1,4)$ and $ (4,+\infty)$, so it has antiderivative at each of these intervals given by

$$F_i(x)=\frac{-1}{3}\ln(|x-1|)+\frac 43\ln(|x-4|)+C_i$$

Comment: In principle you cannot unify as there can be three different constants and you may not integrate across the singularities. But this is unimportant.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Thanks for your remark. i edited it. is it correct now.

Comment: @hamam_Abdallah Yes, I got the same too, but the book says that the answer is $\frac{1}{2}\ln(x^{2}-5x+4)+\frac{5}{6}\ln \frac{x-4}{x-1}+c$